# Allow Woocommerce checkout with an empty cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce has a redirect action on the checkout page, that is triggered when the user's cart is empty. How do I circumvent this redirect, or change the action so that I can allow a user to proceed to checkout on an empty cart.

Use-case is to convert the woocommerce environment to a catalog, and process checkouts with or without cart items as leads.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this myself. As of WC 3.7 --
Traced a filter hook that WooCommerce uses for the redirect on Empty cart.
woocommerce_checout_redirect_empty_cart
[woo documentation here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_template_redirect.html#26)

You can return this hook false in your child theme functions to disable the redirect method that the hook calls back.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review_expired', '__return_false' );
```

Then Voila. Can access your Empty Checkout, and use it in whatever way necessary.